# If $e_0 = \frac{1}{2} $and $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}:e_n=\frac{(2n-1)^2}{2n(2n+1)}e_{n-1}$, find $\sum_{n\geq 0} e_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, game-theory

Consider the following optimal stopping game:  The controller is presented with steps in a fair random walk (fair coin flips, $P(h)=P(t) = \frac{1}{2}$) and at each stage of the game, the controller can stop and take a payoff of $\frac{H}{H+T}$ where $H$ is the number of heads encountered up till that point, and $T$ is the number of tails.

A proposed stopping strategy is to stop the first time the payoff exceeds $\frac{1}{2}$. Note that this strategy does eventually stop, with probability 1. (This is probably in fact the optimal strategy, but that is not the point of this question.) What is the expectation value of the payoff if that strategy is used?

I have been able to calculate the probability $g_m$ of stopping at step $2m+1$ as
$$
g_m = \frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}\frac{1}{m+1} \binom{2m}{m}
$$
and the contribution to the expected payoff is from the possibility of stopping at step $2m+1$ is
$$
e_m = \frac{1}{2} g_m \left( 1+\frac{1}{2m+1} \right)
$$

It is then easy to show that $e_0 = \frac{1}{2}$ and for all integer $n>0$ 
$$
e_n=\frac{(2n-1)^2}{2n(2n+1)}e_{n-1}
$$

To find the expected payoff I need to find
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_n
$$

Thus the question: 
If $e_0 = \frac{1}{2} $and $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}:e_n=\frac{(2n-1)^2}{2n(2n+1)}e_{n-1}$, find $\sum_{n\geq 0} e_n$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}e_n &= \frac{(2 n-1)^2}{(2 n+1) (2 n)} e_{n-1} \\ &=\frac{(2 n-1)^2}{(2 n+1) (2 n)} \frac{(2 n-3)^2}{(2 n-1) (2 n-2)}\cdots \frac{1^2}{3 \cdot 2} \cdot\frac12 \\ &= \frac{(2 n)!}{(2 n+1) n!^2} \frac1{2^{2 n+1}} \end{align} $$

Thus,

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 n)!}{(2 n+1) n!^2} \frac1{2^{2 n+1}} $$

This sum is straightforward.  Consider

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 n)!}{(2 n+1) n!^2} x^{2 n+1} $$

Then

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2 n}{n} x^{2 n} = \left ( 1-4 x^2 \right )^{-1/2}$$

Then

$$f(x) = \frac12 \arcsin{2 x} $$

The sum is then

$$f \left ( \frac12 \right ) = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Comment: Beat me to it (+1)

Comment: Really nice.  I guess my figuring out the ratio of terms was a blind alley, since I had your expression for $e_n$ earlier and decided I couldn't sum it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly longer approach, but it might shed a little more light on how to get the answer without necessarily recognizing the series first.

Start with
$$
\begin{align}
e_n
&=\frac{(2n-1)^2}{2n(2n+1)}e_{n-1}\\
&=\frac12\frac{(2n-1)!!^2}{(2n)!!(2n+1)!!}\\
&=\frac1{2(2n+1)}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\\
&=\frac1{2(2n+1)}\frac{(n-\frac12)(n-\frac32)\cdots\frac12}{n!}\\
&=\frac1{2(2n+1)}\binom{n-\frac12}{n}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n+1)}\binom{-\frac12}{n}\\
\end{align}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_nx^{2n+1}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\binom{-\frac12}{n}x^{2n+1}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^x(-1)^n\binom{-\frac12}{n}t^{2n}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\\
&=\frac12\sin^{-1}(x)
\end{align}
$$
Set $x=1$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_n=\frac\pi4
$$

Comment: @RonGordon: I didn't mean to deprecate your answer at all. I was going to do it essentially your way, but then I thought I might add a bit more to show how one might get the answer without recognizing the series for $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ or $\arcsin(x)$. There is nothing wrong with having some useful series in your repertoire.

Comment: Hey, it's all good.  I hate to put anything less than glowing in a comment on one of your answers and I know you easily would have gotten this first (and pretty much everything else I solve) had I been a hair later.